# How to access json object from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

In my code one of the promise returning the result like this

```
[{"success":true,"fileName":"./tmp/test.txt"}]
```

and I want to convert it into Json. how to convert it?
output:-{"success":true,"fileName":"./tmp/test.txt"}

Comment: data[0].fileName ? Or am I missing something in your question ?

Comment: `var a=[{"success":true,"fileName":"./tmp/test.txt"}];` `console.log(a[0].fileName)`

Comment: @VickyGonsalves, how come we both used `a` for the array variable name?!

Comment: @AdamAzad `a` is first letter came in my mind but I commented 20 seconds earlier than u.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You receive an array containing one object.
Just access array's first element, like :

```
var array = [{"success":true,"fileName":"./tmp/test.txt"}];
var fileName = array[0].fileName;
```

Comment: You should edit your answer, because as written it won't work (`a` should be undefined)